# Why do I get "Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed" with an open connection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I have this code:

```
// this is managed elsewhere
SqlConnection connection =...
connection.Open();

// this is one block of code, separate from the above
using( var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction() ) {
   using( var command = connection.CreateCommand() ) {
     command.Transaction = transaction;
     command.CommandText = ...
     using( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() ) {
         if( reader.HasRows ) {
             if( reader.Read() ) {
                 //get data from the reader
             }
         }
     }
}
```

and this code runs just fine most of the time. Yet sometimes - very rarely - retrieving `HasRows` yields the following exception:

```
Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed.
System.InvalidOperationException
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_HasRows()
  // my code calling HasRows listed here
```

I'm 99,5% sure the connection is open at that very moment. My code uses `HasRows` before reading from the reader [pretty much like MSDN suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

What might be the reason for that exception?

Comment: What kind of application is it(f.e. ASP.NET), where is the connection initialized and declared, is it static, is `Connection-Pooling` enabled, why do you reuse it at all? I would create it in a `using-statement` where you use it.

Comment: Have you checked at that point what the State of the connection is? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx

Comment: @astander: No, otherwise I wouldn't say I'm 99,5% sure.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: That's a class library loader into Windows Azure web role working process and running an infinite loop for days. The connection is not recreated each time to reduce the overhead - I need one connection that is used like every ten seconds so I just keep it open.

Comment: Show your full code?
Also check first if reader !=null

Comment: @Kamran Shahid: My code is gazillion lines and proprietary. If `reader==null` I'd get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: To be proprietary first it should work :)
Don't know what you are doing on those commented code.We do cahgne certain keyword before posting code to avoid proprietary problems in various forums

Comment: @Kamran Shahid: It's gazillion lines anyway and the problem is reproduced quite rarely.

Comment: Are you using parallel programming?
Also have you put nolock sort of hint for your resultset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens to be [unexpected behavior in `ExecuteReader()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14229310/57428) - most likely a bug. Deep inside `ExecuteReader()` some random error occurs, most likely a network timeout, the connection is closed and then a closed `SqlDataReader` is returned as if nothing happened. No wonder subsequent call to `HasRows` yields an exception.

Answer (score 2):

quickfix
you could add a check to see if your connection is open before the hasrows and open your connection again if it is closed

but i would suggest that you add decent logging there too (i'm curious ;) )

Comment: This happens to be connection being closed from inside `ExecuteReader()` - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14255148/57428 and the linked to question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm concerned about your comment above that you are not creating a connection each time. Let connection pooling worry about the overhead. You should be creating a connection each time through. Create the connection, do your reads, destroy the connection. Long lived connections can have intermittant problems with the communication being dropped between the servers (all it takes is a timeout or a few dropped packets).

Answer (score 0):

Have you Declared your DataReader anywhere????

Also if you are having BeginTransaction() function then this function should have a functionality what type of command you want to execute ie executeReader, ExecuteNonQuery etc. First check in your reader :

```
ISReading...
```

then go forward with reader.hasRow.

Also DataReader stores a full table so you should check Tables[0].rows

Comment: Yeap, I declared it: `using( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() ) {`