# How to address SqlConnection being closed from inside ExecuteReader?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005

I have an open `SqlConnection` and code like this:

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()) {
   using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
       command.Transaction = transaction;
   command.CommandText = "MyQueryText";
       using( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() ) {
           //read data
       }
   }
}
```

[I've been experiencing some "impossible code" symptoms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13968342/57428) and subscribed to `SqlConnection.StateChange` event and now I've found that at some point the event is invoked with the following stack (state is being changed from `Open` to `Closed`):

```
at MyHandler.onStateChange(Object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CloseConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Close()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.BreakConnection()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.SetMetaData(_SqlMetaDataSet metaData, Boolean moreInfo)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
// my code calling `ExecuteReader()`
```

so the runtime encounters some random error (network connectivity problem I guess) and closes the connection and then returns a closed reader object to my code and my attempts to use the returned reader yield `InvalidOperationException`.

I need to work it around somehow. Obviously random network errors will happen. I have retry logic in my code that can deal with `SqlException`s thrown on network issues but here I face a closed reader and then an `InvalidOperationException`.

My first idea is to write my own `ExecuteReader()` that would call native `ExecuteReader()`, check whether a closed reader is returned and if that happens throw a new `ClosedReaderReturnedException` and I'll also change the retry code so that it reacts to such exceptions too and reruns the query.

Is my solution good? Is there a better solution?

Comment: file a bug on the connect website.  What happens if you throw from your event?  Will your exception make it back up to execute reader?

Comment: @AbdElRaheim: I will file a bug, but it will take ages to have it fixed or maybe they will even close it as 'by design' and I need a workaround now. This is not reproduced reliably and so I can't really test it thoroughly.

Comment: is it possible to check the state of the connection after you call executereader?  Maybe make an extension method that will call execute reader on command and then check connection state.  Maybe also a method for read() that does the same check

Comment: @AbdElRaheim: That's more or less what I suggest, isn't it?

Comment: oh.  thats a good solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Is there any issue with having retry logic based on any exception (and not on specific SqlException)? I am assuming that exceptions resulting due to programming errors would be eventually found out during testing phase and severe (such as SO) exceptions would anyway not be caught by catch block so generic exception block for retry logic can be acceptable idea.

If not then probably your solution of wrapping `ExecuteReader` would be good idea. Considering that this is [documentated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) behavior, you also need to pay attentions to other exceptions that ExecuteReader method may throw - so you probably may need to anticipate `IOException` and `ObjectDisposedException` apart from `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Retrying on just any exception is a bad idea - it can trigger devastating storm of requests to outside services and paralyze everything.