# How could I workaround cases when SqlDataReader.Read() erroneously returns false?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sqldatareader

I'm facing some transient problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14229310/57428). My program holds an open connection to SQL Azure. It uses the following code to invoke a SQL query:

```
using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()) {
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        command.CommandText = "MyQueryText";
        using( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() ) {
           if( reader.Read() ) {
              //retrieve data
           } else {
              // Control should not get here
              // but sometimes it gets here
              throw new InvalidOperationException()
           }
        } 
   } 
}
```

At some point the program runs the code above and faces `SqlException` with `Class` set to `12` and `Number` set to `-2` and the following text:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

It waits for 15 seconds, closes the connection, opens the connection and runs the code above once again. Most of the time this second attempt is either successful or it yields another `SqlException` with a timeout. Yet sometimes - very rarely - control passes to `if`, then `.Read()` returns `false` and an exception is thrown from my code.

The query is crafted such way that it should return at least one row (and the data in the database is such that the query should return at least one row) and still `.Read()` returns `false`.

This occurs very rarely, randomly and always accompanied with a timeout shortly before that. I suspect that this is some transient problem incorrectly handled by .NET framework. Something like this:

- `.ExecuteReader()` initiates the query
- the server confirms that the query ran successfully
- some network error occurs
- `.Read()` fails to read the data and returns `false`

I need to somehow workaround this problem - preferably such way that if there's a transient problem it is properly diagnosed and a proper exception is thrown to the caller code and the retry logic handles this. Something like this:

```
using( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() ) {
   if( reader.Read() ) {
      //retrieve data
   } else if (reader.SomeTransientProblemOccured {
       throw new RetryTheQueryException();
   } else {
       throw new InvalidOperationException()
   } 
}
```

but I have no idea how to identify that there was that transient problem.

How do I know that `SqlDataReader.Read()` returns `false` because of a transient problem and not because there was no data returned?

Comment: This is a strange problem... Did you try to listen the event InfoMessage of the SqlConnection class ?

Comment: I doubt that such an egregious bug exists in a piece of code that runs on millions of servers every day in exactly this use case. It is very likely that the bug is yours. For debugging purposes, change the query to `SELECT 1`. Is the problem still reproducible?

Comment: there is a [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934(v=pandp.50).aspx) in  Microsoft Enterprise Library, it might be helpful

Comment: @usr: Have you seen the linked to post? That bug is real yet not very well known and I guess it is of the same nature.

Comment: @schglurps: I'll try to make use of that event. However if there's a network problem I would expect the callback to not arrive.

Comment: I have seen the linked post it but I'm not convinced it is a real bug. I have looked at the entire call chain posted here and there's just no place an error is swallowed. I also found the place where it is thrown. My advice would be to create a small repo (maybe execute `WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:2' with 1sec timeout. Do that in a loop on 1000 threads.).

Comment: @usr: That one reproduces something like once per month and the workaround which checks the reader object is not in "closed" state works just fine. So no small repro in this century.